# CSS: Importance of specifying object over generic dot?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Given

```
<div class="foo">
    <span class="bar"></span>
</div>
```

I've always defined the CSS classes as:

```
.foo
{

}
.bar
{

}
```

Is specifying the object important, or ultimately for readability so you can quickly see which sort of element you are searching for when editing?  IE:

```
div.foo
{

}
span.bar
{

}
```

Comment: just fyi the 'object' is called an element (div element, span element)  (not trying to be a wiseass, sorry :P)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will be important for element specificity.

`.foo` targets **any** element that has a class of `"foo"`.

`div.foo` targets **only** `<div>`s that have a class of `"foo"`. That means other elements with that class aren't selected.

If you're sure only one kind of element will ever bear a given class, I guess there's nothing wrong with prefixing the class selector with the element name for readability, or leaving it out completely if you're lazy to type.

However, if you think other elements might bear this class — for instance if it's a pretty generic name like `left`, `larger-font` or `sep`, it's a good idea to do this so you're sure you're styling the right elements.

If there are any common styles shared by any elements with a given class, you specify just the class selector and add the common styles there, then after that specify any styles that pertain to each individual element. For example:

```
.foo { /* Generic styles for foo class */ }
div.foo { /* Styles for <div>s with foo class */ }
blockquote.foo { /* Styles for <blockquote>s with foo class */ }
```

Comment: Why would you have another element with the same class if it's not defined?

Comment: I use this `div.foo` notation when I have styles I want to recreate in different elements like `div.blue-text` and `span.blue-text` for example.